# Downgraded my target .Net framework and now compiler cannot see referenced dlls, but intellisense can

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, versioning

I have an Umbraco/MVC project I have been working on using the current ( 6.1.6 ) version of Umbraco and  building with the .Net Framework version 4.5.

I created the project as an empty MVC project then installed Umbraco through NuGet.

When it came to deployment time, my project didn't work on the live server because it turns out that only has the 4.0 version of the .net framework on it. I changed the "Build" property on my Visual Studio 2012 project so that it would target the older framework and as if by magic it now won't build at all.

I realised there was a versioning problem with the Umbraco dlls, so I downloaded the binaries again and installed them in the /bin folder on the production server. That now works correctly, but my local version still won't build with the 4.0 target, even though I am now referencing the current dll versions.

The thing that does my head in is that I can *see* the files.

The compiler says:

> The type or namespace name 'editorControls' does not exist in the namespace 'umbraco' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Glenatron\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\usercontrols\customUpload.ascx.cs

The line `using umbraco.editorControls.userControlGrapper` has a wavy blue line under `editorControls` but if I start typing out the line again, intellisense has no problem identifying it.

I don't think this is really about Umbraco, I assume it is something to do with my environment in general.

I have emptied the bin folder and replaced my local reference dlls with ones downloaded from the Umbraco site. I have also removed and re-added all my references, to no avail. There are no versioned references in my csproj file.

I realise this is a relatively common problem - can anyone shed any light on what I need to do?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I did manage to work around it, but I think I had to do something really arcane, possibly copying all my code into a new project targeted on the new framework ( which is not too hard if you tell git to ignore all the binaries ) which is not really a solution, but got me up and running.

Comment: I just figured it out by deleting all the reference which caused problems. Then restarted visual, next added previous references and did a rebuild.